# BCP Errors: String data, right truncation; Unexpected EOF

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

OK... I give up.  I have been struggling with trying to import a semicolon-separated file (field1;field2) with BCP for the past two days, but I only have been getting these errors:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
```

A notepad++ screenshot of my input files is below:
[image: Some fields have spaces before the semicolon]
Please note that some fields can have whitespace before the semicolon.

I don't need to import all fields, so I created a format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" />
<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="4" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" />
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="24" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="14" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="4" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="4" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" />
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="120" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" />
  <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="128" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
</RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="Municipio" xsi:type="SQLNUMERIC" PRECISION="18" SCALE="0"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="Placa" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Categoria" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Taxa" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Autenticacao" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Chassi" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Cor" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="MarcaModelo" xsi:type="SQLNUMERIC" PRECISION="18" SCALE="0"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="TipoServico" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="Destino" xsi:type="SQLNUMERIC" PRECISION="18" SCALE="0"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="TipoVeiculo" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Please also note that fields are not ordered.

My command line is

```
 bcp [dbname].dbo.dbTable in input.txt -f format.fmt -T
```

I am truly and hopelessly lost... If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

BULK INSERT fails as well.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It looks like the last field in the row (02-CARGA in example) is attempting to be inserted into a numeric column. obviously that is not the error you are getting but since that looks incorrect and your example doesn't include all 19 fields it tough to tell exactly where the error is. Double check your types in your format file.

Comment: @BobKlimes: thanks for the hint.  I have checked this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx) and MS tells us the `bcp` ignores the `<row>` element when bulk importing.  Quoting: "Instead, bcp loads the data based on the column types of the target table.".  More lost than ever... :(

Comment: A word of advice: I always import data from flat files into a staging table, with columns that are purposely oversized - usually `nvarchar(255)` for everything, unless some field is larger than that. It's much easier to sanitize and normalize the data after the import rather than trying to do it during.

Comment: @pbal I have to ask: Are the types in your target table consistent with the data that that is going in?

Comment: @BobKlimes: I have rechecked this and re-read the documentation.  It seems BCP won't work, so I am focusing on BULK INSERT now.  I am taking dartonw's advice and will restart with a staging table and build from there.  Will post results and an eventual final answer.  It can't be this difficult...